# Translating yaw pitch and roll into real yaw pitch and roll

Tags: c#, dictionary, machine-learning

I have this headtracker configuration: http://sketchfab.com/show/f63e7aa5e8d54b79b5d1bd0ae0a5f739 (It's a 3d viewer, use your mouse to rotate)

The blue box is where the headtracker is and what it looks like. It is slightly tilted, vertical and translated from the center of rotation so the standard yaw pitch roll do not work, rather it's a combination of all values.

Goal is to translate the yaw pitch and roll into real yaw pitch and roll.

Output of the headtracker is

```
value1 = -Pi ... Pi
value2 = -Pi/2 ... Pi/2
value3 = -Pi ... Pi
```

As you are eager to know what I tried I want to tell you:

1. Machine learning. I rotated the head with headtracker to well-defined angles and trained a model with it, ie features were value1, value2 and value3, label was the angle. Couldn't find a model each time resp. did each model have an accuracy of 0 per cent.
2. Dictionary. Used value1, value2 and value3 on one side and angle on the other. It did this only for rotation in one plane. Using this method, a slight change in rotation plane rendered the approach useless. Not sure how all planes can be included and whether this can be used to interpolate.

What else could I do that maps value1, value2 and value3 properly to yaw, pitch and roll?

Comment: This is a "Change of Basis" problem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: @J... How to determine the appropriate transformation matrix?

Comment: It's a big enough problem.  I guess you could solve it mathematically or empirically.  The idea with the latter is that you make a pure unit movement in each axis (ie: from a defined 'zero' position, move X number of degrees in each axis and record the output, normalize, and call each the new basis vector for yaw, pitch, and roll).  Whether there is degeneracy with such a solution will affect whether it is possible or not - a full analytical solution would tell you that.  It depends on how the device measures (with reference to itself (gyro?) or some external detector (antenna?)).

Comment: Personally, if I were designing this system, I would probably have made better effort to mount the tracking device naturally orthogonal to the human head.  Top center seems like a better location, but at the side or rear is ok so long as it aligns with the axes of the human head.  A small range for user-adjustment also makes sense - then you can simply (physically) adjust and calibrate for each person.  If it were my project, I'd consider a physical re-design over a mathematically heavy band-aid.

Comment: @J... It's sensor fusion, gyro+acc+magnetometer.